# Android app Matter integration - not able to connect the device

Tags: android, iot, nsdateformatter, formatter, matter.js

I am trying to run the google sample POC for the matter with the module ESP32, sharing the url link which I am referring to is [here](https://developers.home.google.com/codelabs/matter-sample-app#1).

But I am not able to stablish the connection, intermittent call back is coming in the "onCommissioningRequested" under the "AppCommissioningService" class but after that not getting the success/failure call back with below method.

```
commissioningServiceDelegate
          .sendCommissioningComplete(
              CommissioningCompleteMetadata.builder().setToken(deviceId.toString()).build())
          .addOnSuccessListener {
            MyCustomLogger.d(
                "Commissioning: OnSuccess for commissioningServiceDelegate.sendCommissioningComplete()")
          }
          .addOnFailureListener { ex ->
            MyCustomLogger.e("Commissioning: Failed to send commissioning complete.", ex)
          }
```

After waiting the few minutes I am receiving the timeout.
Please help where is this failing and how can I get success in this.